# Resizing UICollectionViewCells on rotation changes currently visible cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a paginated, horizontally scrolling `UICollectionView` where each cell takes up the size of the view/device screen, and one cell appears at a time.  I'm experiencing an issue where on device rotation, the cells will transition to the correct new size, but the position of the cells will be off.

Before Rotation:

[image: Before Rotation]

After Rotation:

[image: After Rotation]

On rotation, how can I not only resize the collection view cells properly but ensure that the current cell stays visible?

I've boiled this problem down to a very simple example without a custom flow layout.

Setting the size of the cells to the `collectionView` frame's size (the collection view is the size of the view controller holding it):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return collectionView.frame.size
}
```

Attempting to handle rotation in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    guard let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else { return }

    flowLayout.itemSize = collectionView.frame.size

    flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Actually, if I call `invalidateLayout()` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, setting the `itemSize` here shouldn't be necessary, as `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` will be called when the layout is recreated.

I've also tried manually scrolling to the first visible cell during rotation after setting the new itemSize, but that shows no improvement:

```
if let item = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems().first {
    collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(item, atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should handle content offset of your `UICollectionView`, so in your view controller try to override `viewWillTransitionToSize` function from `UIContentContainer` protocol, like this:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    let offset = yourCollectionView?.contentOffset;
    let width  = yourCollectionView?.bounds.size.width;

    let index     = round(offset!.x / width!);
    let newOffset = CGPointMake(index * size.width, offset!.y);

    yourCollectionView?.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: false)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (context) in
        yourCollectionView?.reloadData()
        yourCollectionView?.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: false)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```